# JavaScript - I try to fetch data to database but it return statusCode: 400

Tags: javascript, mongodb, strapi

I have successfully implemented DS18B20 on Raspberry Pi with Gatsby frontend.
My next step, put all temperature data to the mongodb which I use STRAPI as a backend.
The following is my code in server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);
const ds18b20 = require('ds18b20');
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const port = 4001;

const interval = 1000;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  var sensorId = [];

  ds18b20.sensors((err, id) => {
    sensorId = id;
    socket.emit('sensors', id);
  });

  setInterval(() => {
    sensorId.forEach((id) => {
      ds18b20.temperature(id, (err, value) => {
        socket.emit('temps', {'id': id, 'value': value});
      });
    });
  }, interval);

  setInterval(() => {
    sensorId.forEach((id) => {
      ds18b20.temperature(id, (err, value) => {
        var tempData = {
          temperature: value,
          date: new Date()
        };
        fetch('http://172.20.10.3:1337/weathers', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(tempData),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      });
    });
  }, 10000);

});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

It return the following log:

```
Dec 20 23:47:41 raspberrypi node[5195]: {
Dec 20 23:47:41 raspberrypi node[5195]:   statusCode: 400,
Dec 20 23:47:41 raspberrypi node[5195]:   error: 'Bad Request',
Dec 20 23:47:41 raspberrypi node[5195]:   message: 'ValidationError',
Dec 20 23:47:41 raspberrypi node[5195]:   data: { errors: { temperature: [Array] } }
Dec 20 23:47:41 raspberrypi node[5195]: }
```

How can I fetch by using POST method to STRAPI?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it, I just change the value to String by .toString().

```
var tempData = {
          temperature: value,
          date: new Date()
        };
```

to

```
var tempData = {
          temperature: value.toString(),
          date: new Date()
        };
```